# Old prior art requests

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are prior art requests here that are not "valid" anymore as the aplication has since become a patent.

Example:
[Prior art request for US20120179309 "Data Improvement System and Method"?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12639/18033)

I retagged it from pre-grant to post-grant, but dont think thats the solution. In this case, the patent seems to have narrow(ed?) claims, so maybe even the question itself is outdated.

Any ideas what to do with those questions?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if prior art requests in reference to claims that are no longer pending (due to being narrowed) would be off-topic as being "hypothetical" or "no actual problem to be solved" (per [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

In this case, they should be closed.

Comment: Or count as rejected because of having been narrowed?